# How to add a try_future::map_ok::MapOk to a Vec<impl Future>

Tags: rust, async-await, future

I have this function that returns an `impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<Image>, reqwest::Error>>` without any issue. The compiler doesn't complain about anything:

```rust
fn future_images<'a>(
    image_ids: &'a str,
    client: &'a Client,
    file_id: &'a str,
    frames: &'a [Node],
    scale: usize,
    format: &'a str,
) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<Image>, reqwest::Error>> + 'a {
    get_images_url_collection(image_ids, client, file_id, scale, format)
        .map_ok(move |urls| to_images(frames, &urls, scale, format))
}
```

I was testing to add this `MapOk` future to a vector of futures inside a function, but then I get a compiler error which says `expected type parameter impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<Image>, reqwest::Error>> + 'a, found struct futures_util::future::try_future::map_ok::MapOk`. You can see the code below.

```rust
fn future_images2<'a>(
    futures: &mut Vec<impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<Image>, reqwest::Error>> + 'a>,
    image_ids: &'a str,
    client: &'a Client,
    file_id: &'a str,
    frames: &'a [Node],
    scale: usize,
    format: &'a str,
) {
    let fim = get_images_url_collection(image_ids, client, file_id, scale, format)
        .map_ok(move |urls| to_images(frames, &urls, scale, format));
    futures.push(fim);
}
```

Why is this happening here and not in the first function? Why does the compiler behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `impl SomeTrait` as (part of) the type for a function parameter means that the *caller* of the function gets to choose the actual type. However here, when you call `futures.push (fim)`, you are trying to put a specific type of value inside `futures` and there is no reason why this type would be the same as the type chosen by the caller. You will either need to specify the full type of the future in the parameters (which will probably be pretty cumbersome) or to box it:

```
fn future_images2<'a> (
    futures: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<Image>>, reqwest::Error>> + 'a>,
    image_ids: &'a str,
    client: &'a Client,
    file_id: &'a str,
    frames: &'a [Node],
    scale: usize,
    format: &'a str,
) {
    let fim = get_images_url_collection (image_ids, client, file_id, scale, format)
        .map_ok (move |urls| to_images (frames, &urls, scale, format));
    futures.push (Box::new (fim));
}
```

Comment: it makes total sense! Thanks for your answer! Kudos!